# Azure Data Warehouse Database Storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am new to Azure Data Warehouse and little confused while reading some articles as to where the data is actually stored. Is it the compute nodes that store the data for the db tables or the azure blob storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Azure Documentation..

> SQL Data Warehouse is a massively parallel processing (MPP) distributed database system. By dividing data and processing capability across multiple nodes, SQL Data Warehouse can offer huge scalability - far beyond any single system. Behind the scenes, **SQL Data Warehouse spreads your data across many shared-nothing storage and processing units. The data is stored in Premium locally redundant storage, and linked to compute nodes for query execution**. With this architecture, SQL Data Warehouse takes a "divide and conquer" approach to running loads and complex queries. Requests are received by the Control node, optimized and then passed to the Compute nodes to do their work in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.